# CREAT A CONDITION ON .LOC FUNCTION WORKING WITH A LIST OF LABELS

Tags: indexing, pandas-loc

***I have two dataframes with kinds of foods on indexs:***

df_1.index.name = 'foods_column'

df_2.index.name = 'foods_column'

| df_1 | df_2 |
| --- | --- |
| **foods_column** | **foods_column** |
| rice | rice |
| nuts | nuts |
| pizza | coffee |
| coffee | coffee |
| nutella | nutella |
| milk | milk |

***I want to select only this labels:***

labels =["rice", "nuts", "pizza"]

df_1_new = df_1.loc[labels]

df_2_new = df_2.loc[labels]

---

***But "pizza" don't appear in df_2, and py give me this error:***

---

KeyError: "['pizza'] not in index"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df_2_new = df_2.loc[df_2["foods_column"].isin(labels)]
```

See more info here
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html